# arraylist to play with playback

Tags: android, playback

I am getting list of mp3 files(as a ArrayList(Path)) from local by choosing one by one but I could not able to make them to play one by one play if finished move to next and if finished all list loop again. any help?

Answer (score 0):

I solved issue thansk to : http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/musicdroid-audio-player-part-i

ofcourse I did a little bit modification, like:

```
   private void playSong() {
        try {

            mp.reset();
            mp.setDataSource(playlist.get(currentPosition));
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();

            // Setup listener so next song starts automatically
            mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
                    nextSong();
                }

            });

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.v(getString(R.string.app_name), e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void nextSong() {
        if (++currentPosition >= playlist.size()) {
            // Last song, just reset currentPosition
            currentPosition = 0;
        } else {
            // Play next song
            playSong(/*MEDIA_PATH + playlist.get(currentPosition)*/);
        }
    }
```